# Multiple lines deletion in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to adjust height of `UITextView` programmatically in `objective c` when the user types/deletes characters. It works perfectly for me as long as user does not delete multiple lines at a time. So, the main question is how could we detect multiple lines deletion in `UITextView` and get this number of lines (adjustment of height is easy afterwards).

Comment: What do you aim for? Like you want to adjust the height of the text view to fit the content?

Comment: Yep, programmatically. The only issue is to determine the number of lines deleted by the user.

Comment: Upon sequential character deletions - no problem. If user decides deleting 3-4 lines I need to know it and adjust the UI respectively.

Comment: I would approach the problem in other way by inspecting the change in `textView.contentSize` since `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` it will automatically adjust its `contentSize` to fit the text inside. You can use a delegation or KVO to detect the change.

Comment: In fact, if you set `textView.scrollEnable` to `NO` then its `intrinsicSize` will always fit the content which will allow you to work with the auto layout and have text view grow automatically as the user type without having to write any code.

Comment: I need to retain scrollable behavior

Comment: Maybe I could just set it to `NO`, then change to `YES`, thinking...

Comment: Anyway, if you want to keep the scrollability then just read `textView.contentSize`. If you set your frame to that size, it will fit the content.

Comment: Still, I have dependent background that should grow and shrink together with the `UITextView`, so anyway it should be solved by adjusting `CGRect` of it.

Comment: refer this link http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms

Comment: Nope, not that easy. Another issue (besides dependent background) is that `UITextView` should move upwards upon clicking it, same way as it is done in 'what's up'. And so, `UITextView` is just growing downwards, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Oh, ok, will see, thank you!

Comment: No, still struggling with it. Really need to know number of lines deleted...

Comment: You should not rely on counting the lines, but try to dynamically compute the textView height after user finishes editing, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5641169/2710486) will help you.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically for multiple lines, but this method could help you know the change in range of characters in UITextView

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
 {
  char toDelete = [textView.text characterAtIndex:range.location];

    int duplicateCharCount = 0;
    for(int i =range.location-1; i>=0; i--) {

        if([textView.text characterAtIndex:i] == toDelete) {
            duplicateCharCount++;
        } else {
            break;
        }  
    }

    NSRange newRange = NSMakeRange(0, range.location - duplicateCharCount);
    [textView setText:[textView.text substringWithRange:newRange]];

    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```

But for your scenario, you can calculate number of lines by knowing frame size of your textview like this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font 
                  constrainedToSize:myUITextView.frame.size 
                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // default mode
float numberOfLines = size.height / font.lineHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in `textViewDidChange` delegate method of `UITextView`:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```